# Will I lose my applications and desktop customizations when I upgrade to a new release?

Tags: upgrade

To begin I must a say that I am a complete noob to any form of Linux but am enjoying learning to use Ubuntu and finding an alternative to Windows.

My question is, after having installed 13.10 (dual boot), added programs, and customized it to where it's a good alternative to Win 7 (for me any way), what will happen when I upgrade to 14.x?

Will I be able to do the upgrade and not lose my customization or will it be like starting over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A release upgrade will remove some packages from your system, but in general most of the packages being used currently will be updated to new versions and your system and most of the applications you use at the moment will remain the same.

About customizations we are talking about a different story:

- If you are talking about simple customizations, eg: wallpaper and the size of your launcher icons, then nothing will probably change;
- Other more in depth system changes can be eventually reversed by the upgrade and the customization effects will need to be re applied with updated versions of the tools you used to customize your desktop.

14.04 is the next LTS, once you upgrade you will probably be happy with it and enjoy 5 long years of support and stability. I would say that its better to upgrade and test than to worry now. If you need to re-install and least do it only if necessary and if you are worried about stability then do it for a LTS version as 14.04.

Comment: Just for reference's sake: my wallpaper did change on upgrading.